# Changing Java classes to Stored procedure

Tags: java, xml, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a java file name "**E2BXmlParser**" where I am reading and manipulating the XML data fetched from the database.

Now I am trying to execute the java file using Oracle SQL Developer after changing the file like this

```
    CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "E2BXmlParser" AS

    --(Rest of Code).
```

Now it is asking for multiple values that are used in code but this is not the case when I am executing the java file from command line like this

```
loadjava -user  username/password@DBalias -r E2BXmlParser.java
```

Please help.
P.S (Java file has multiple classes and methods)

Comment: *"P.S (Java file has multiple classes and methods)"*
Do you have a separate `CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED ...` block for each of the Top Level Class (not only for each java file)? What is the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your (Rest of Code) is Java (possibly containing '&' characters), is that the case? If so, you don't need to do that after using loadjava. You just need to create a wrapper function like this:

`SQL>     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION E2BXmlParser_Parse
  2      RETURN VARCHAR2
  3      AS LANGUAGE JAVA
  4      NAME 'E2BXmlParser.Parse() return java.lang.String';`

I know I'm making a lot of assumptions here, just trying to get the point across.